# Struggling to add a stop loss using strategy.exit, it keeps adding too many orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have tried adding a stop loss but no matter what I try it keeps either not adding a stop loss or adding over 3000 orders and not working. Here is the code I have so far (all the strategy bits) any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
var int long_active = 0
var int short_active = 0

if(hour == 23)
    short_active := 0
    long_active := 0
    strategy.cancel_all()
    strategy.close_all()

if (current > prev and 2<hour and hour<23)
    short_active := 0
    strategy.cancel("short_exit")
    strategy.close("short")
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="long")
    strategy.exit("long_exit", "long",stop = stop_loss)

if (current < prev and 2<hour and hour<23)
    long_active := 0
    strategy.cancel("long_exit")
    strategy.close("long")
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="short")
    strategy.exit("short_exit", "short", stop = stop_loss)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your `strategy.exit()` calls in the global scope. As it is, they will only be called whenever your if conditions are `true`.

You can add a direction check to prevent unnecessary calls.

```
if (current > prev and 2<hour and hour<23)
    short_active := 0
    strategy.cancel("short_exit")
    strategy.close("short")
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment="long")

if (current < prev and 2<hour and hour<23)
    long_active := 0
    strategy.cancel("long_exit")
    strategy.close("long")
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short, comment="short")

if (strategy.position_size > 0) // Long
    strategy.exit("long_exit", "long",stop = stop_loss)

if (strategy.position_size < 0) // Short
    strategy.exit("short_exit", "short", stop = stop_loss)
```